# Can't call examples in FiPy when installed from conda

Tags: python, fipy

I installed FiPy following the site's preferred method of conda installation in a virtual environment. However, I can't seem to call/run any of the examples using, for instance, command such as `python setup.py test --examples`. I was also unsuccessful when I tried to run individual examples, e.g. the one listed on the main site as `examples/diffusion/mesh1D.py`. A search of the file name `mesh1D.py` shows that there's no `examples` directory available at all under any fipy directory.

Is this simply an issue with all conda install, which omits the examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [Installation](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/INSTALLATION.html):

> When installed via conda or pip, FiPy will not include its examples.
>   These can be obtained by [cloning the repository](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/INSTALLATION.html#cloning-the-repository)
>   or [downloading a compressed archive](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/download/).